# concat turns values to nan data

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
gg=df_met[['Less','Middle','Greater']].resample('h').mean()
Filtered_mean=Filtered[['Conc']].resample('h').mean()

result = pd.concat([Filtered_mean, gg], axis=1, join_axes=[df1.index])
Reduced_result=result.dropna(axis=0,how='any')
```

Where gg is a file:

```
                         Less    Middle   Greater
Date                                             


2004-02-27 00:00:00  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 01:00:00  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 02:00:00  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 03:00:00  0.083333  0.916667  0.000000
2004-02-27 04:00:00  0.583333  0.416667  0.000000
2004-02-27 05:00:00  0.083333  0.916667  0.000000
2004-02-27 06:00:00  0.666667  0.333333  0.000000
2004-02-27 07:00:00  0.750000  0.250000  0.000000
2004-02-27 08:00:00  0.250000  0.750000  0.000000
2004-02-27 09:00:00  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 10:00:00  0.250000  0.750000  0.000000
2004-02-27 11:00:00  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 12:00:00  0.916667  0.083333  0.000000
2004-02-27 13:00:00  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 14:00:00  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 15:00:00  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 16:00:00  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 17:00:00  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 18:00:00  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
2004-02-27 19:00:00  0.083333  0.916667  0.000000
2004-02-27 20:00:00  0.000000  0.500000  0.500000
2004-02-27 21:00:00  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
2004-02-27 22:00:00  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
2004-02-27 23:00:00  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
2004-02-28 00:00:00  0.000000  0.666667  0.333333
2004-02-28 01:00:00  0.000000  0.833333  0.166667
2004-02-28 02:00:00  0.000000  0.166667  0.833333
2004-02-28 03:00:00  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
2004-02-28 04:00:00  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
2004-02-28 05:00:00  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
```

etc

And Filtered_mean is:

```
                       Conc
2004-02-27 15:00  30.166667
2004-02-27 16:00  24.218182
2004-02-27 17:00  44.781818
2004-02-27 18:00  15.200000
2004-02-27 19:00  33.490000
2004-02-27 20:00  17.100000
2004-02-27 21:00  15.470000
2004-02-27 22:00  13.100000
2004-02-27 23:00  17.736364
2004-02-28 00:00  19.225000
2004-02-28 01:00   9.760000
2004-02-28 02:00   2.737500
2004-02-28 03:00   4.175000
2004-02-28 04:00   2.990000
2004-02-28 05:00   4.983333
2004-02-28 06:00   3.370000
2004-02-28 07:00   2.983333
2004-02-28 08:00   3.508333
2004-02-28 09:00   2.641667
2004-02-28 10:00   4.916667
2004-02-28 11:00   7.100000
2004-02-28 12:00  11.609091
2004-02-28 13:00   5.540000
2004-02-28 14:00   3.025000
2004-02-28 15:00   5.127273
2004-02-28 16:00  11.660000
2004-02-28 17:00   5.833333
2004-02-28 18:00   8.183333
2004-02-28 19:00  -0.158333
2004-02-28 20:00   6.575000
```

When I concate them

```
                      Conc  Less  Middle  Greater
Date                                              
2004-02-27 15:00  30.166667   NaN     NaN      NaN
2004-02-27 15:00  30.166667   NaN     NaN      NaN
2004-02-27 15:00  30.166667   NaN     NaN      NaN
2004-02-27 16:00  24.218182   NaN     NaN      NaN
```

Is this because for the one the index column is an integer

```
dtype='int64', length=34342, freq='H')
```

and for "gg" its a datetime.

```
dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=42479, freq='H')
```

If so how does one convert the whole frame to the other?

The full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import io 
import numpy as np
names=['Date','Wind Speed','Wind Direction']
df2 = pd.read_csv('Met_12_13.csv', index_col=0, names=names, parse_dates=[0])
df_met=df2
df_met.insert(2,'Less','Nan')
df_met.insert(3,'Middle','Nan')
df_met.insert(4,'Greater','Nan')
for line in df2:
    flag1=(df2['Wind Speed']<4)
    flag1=flag1.astype(int)
    flag2=(df2['Wind Speed']>=4 ) & (df2['Wind Speed']<=10)
    flag2=flag2.astype(int)
    flag3=(df2['Wind Speed']>10)
    flag3=flag3.astype(int)

    df_met['Less']=flag1
    df_met['Middle']=flag2
    df_met['Greater']=flag3



aethalometer=['Date','Chanel0','Chanel1','Chanel2','Chanel3','Chanel4','Chanel5','Chanel6','Chanel7']
#df1=pd.read_csv('result.txt', index_col=0,sep='\n', names=aethalometer, parse_dates=[0])
df1 = pd.read_csv('Ath_12_13.csv', sep=',', names=aethalometer ) #Spirows=1
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], errors='coerce')
for y in range (0,6):
    x=y+1
    df1[aethalometer[x]]= pd.to_numeric(df1[aethalometer[x]], errors='coerce')
    df1=df1[df1[aethalometer[x]]>-250]
    df1=df1[df1[aethalometer[x]]<500]
    df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], errors='coerce')
    df1.index



print(len(df1))
#df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('Output14.csv'), parse_dates=[0], names=['Date','A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H'])
#df_mean = df1[['Conc']].resample('h').mean()
print("here")

#df1.index = df1.index.to_period('h')
df_met['per'] = df_met.index.to_period('h')

#df_mean.index=df_mean.index.to_period('h')
#print(len(df_mean)) 
pers = df_met.loc[(df2['Wind Direction'] > 340) | (df_met['Wind Direction'] < 12) , 'per'].unique()

print (pers)
print("here")
#%%
Filtered=df1.drop(pers)
#del Filtered['Date']

a=Filtered['Chanel1']
a.index = pd.to_datetime(a.index, errors='coerce')

b=Filtered['Chanel2']
b.index = pd.to_datetime(b.index, errors='coerce')

c=Filtered['Chanel3']
c.index = pd.to_datetime(c.index, errors='coerce')

d=Filtered['Chanel4']
d.index = pd.to_datetime(d.index, errors='coerce')

e=Filtered['Chanel5']
e.index = pd.to_datetime(e.index, errors='coerce')

f=Filtered['Chanel0']
f.index = pd.to_datetime(f.index, errors='coerce')

g=Filtered['Chanel7']
g.index = pd.to_datetime(g.index, errors='coerce')

a=a.resample('h').mean()
a_median=a.resample('h').median()  #This is how you would make it median
b=b.resample('h').mean()
c=c.resample('h').mean()
d=d.resample('h').mean()
e=e.resample('h').mean()
f=f.resample('h').mean()
g = pd.to_numeric(g, errors='coerce')
g=g.resample('h').mean()

Series=pd.concat([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],join='outer',axis=1)

gg=df_met[['Less','Middle','Greater']].resample('h').mean()

result_mean = pd.concat([Series, gg], axis=1, join_axes=[gg.index])
Reduced_result_mean=result_mean.dropna(axis=0,how='any')

Reduced_result_mean.to_csv("Final2012-13.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

yes indeed. You should have consistent index types across the two dataframes.

Use

```
filtered_mean.reset_index(inplace=True)
filtered_mean['date']=pd.to_datetime(filtered_mean['date'])
filtered_mean.set_index('date',inplace=True)
```

Now both `filtered_mean` and `gg` should have datetime indices.

Comment: it doesn't recorgnise what Date is, how would I convert the Filtered_mean to work with the index itself?

Comment: Also I did it for a test file, and it worked perfectly but in that scenario both elements were for some reason detected as: integers not Dates. So can I make gg an integer from a date?

Comment: Actually probably better, to have them both as datetime

Comment: @SLE, column names are case-specific. Check if your date variable is called 'Date' or 'date'

Comment: Its 'Date' so I used that, but I am thinking that its due to the number of columns.

Comment: My goal: Is to end up with a CSV file that has

Date, Conc, Less, Middle,Greater,Multiple 
27-Feb-2005 12:00, 5.7, 1.0,0,0 
Where the last 4 columss are defined as true or false based on the other datafile wind speed column. (It's very hard to explain online so please bear with)

Whats not working is that those numbers become Nan when I concat them, and I think its because of the data format between the two, that they are not alligned. And probably to do with the first column index

Comment: have you transformed the columns that you use as index in a proper datetimeindex format as I suggested?

Comment: Yeah, it came up with:

    KeyError: 'date'

On this line:
Filtered_mean['Date']=pd.to_datetime(Filtered_mean['date'])

Comment: type `Filtered_mean.columns.tolist()` and tell me what you see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116094/discussion-between-noobie-and-sle).